# django: How to know reason for not authenticated

Tags: django

I am trying to test username and raw password on Django Shell using authenticate function

```
    username = "test@test.com"
    raw_password = "password"
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=raw_password)
```

I know this user name and password does not exist. When i run this code the `user` is returned as `None`. Is there a way i get some failed status or failed reason.

I want to send the failed reason to my application, like email not valid or password not valid or user is not active or for whatever reason its not authenticating.

Comment: authenticate does not check whether the user is active. And it does not tell you whether the problem is the username or password on purpose: that would be a security risk.

Comment: is there any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested btw, but should work!! ( Only checking if the user exists and if the password is the correct for the user, and if is active)

```
from django.contrib import messages

if user is not None:
    if not user.is_active:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Account has been disabled!')
    # do what you want
else:
    try:
        x = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Invalid email!')
    else:
        if not x.check_password(password):
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Invalid password!')
```

Comment: Ok. This indirect method looks the only way.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi This doens't check everything but check more than nothing!! and you can use another thing that is not messages, but the messages framework is a good framework to use!

Comment: @Micolho `.objects.get(<lookup>)` doesn't return `None` but raises `DoesNotExist` (code fixed).

Comment: Note that this won't necessarily work with all auth.backends. Also, being too specific in auth error messages might leak some personal informations.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ty, for editting my code!! and I never used this cause I think the same way... In my opinion only a alert with "Failed to login" is enough!!